# How to manually trigger a TouchEvent in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to trigger the touch event manually but i can't able to call.
this was possible in JavaScript but TypeScript can't able to achieve.

Example:

```
 let touchStart: TouchEvent = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
 touchStart.initEvent('touchstart', true, true);
 element.dispatchEvent(touchStart);
```

If I tried this I can able to trigger touchStart event but I can't able to get the `changedTouches[0].pageX` and `changedTouches[0].pageY`

based on [this link](https://gist.github.com/morewry/538efb737ed9c4e432e4) i have tried like as below,

```
 touchStart.changedTouches = [
    pageX: x
    pageY: y
  ]
```

But I can't able to assign the value in `changedTouches` because of that property is readonly.

How to achieve this? with `changedTouches` in TypeScript?

Comment: Very interestingly, it seems as though TypeScript doesn't properly support the creation of `TouchEvent`s, neither through `new TouchEvent` nor through the older `document.createEvent()`. I'd file a bug but I'm a bit short of time at the moment.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it is a bug?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a real bug in TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an actual bug with TypeScript's `lib.d.ts` which defines how the types of everything in JavaScript and the DOM look like.

I've opened a [ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14435) and a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14436) to fix this issue.

If they get accepted, you can expect the standard way of `new TouchEvent(eventType, initArguments);` to work in future versions of TypeScript.

See [this MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for the correct way of doing it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been trying to trigger touch events in TypeScript, and hit upon the same issues. Looking into it, I saw how the Angular Material team got around this in their tests, so I took a similar approach. Below is example of the code I'm using to mock TouchEvents with `touchstart` and the `changedTouches` mock array being set:

```
let te = createTouchEvent(parentHtmlElement, 'touchstart');
parentHtmlElement.dispatchEvent(te);

function createTouchEvent(touchTarget: HTMLElement, type: string) {        
    const event = document.createEvent('UIEvent');    
    event.initUIEvent(type, true, true, window, 0);

    let touches = [{target: touchTarget}];

    Object.defineProperties(event, {
      changedTouches: {value: touches}
    });    
    return event;
}
```

In my components I am listening for the events as follows:

```
 this.touchStartListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'touchstart', (event: TouchEvent) => {
                    this.handleTouchStart(event);
                });
```

This works very well, no TypeScript warnings, and the events are triggered and handled in my tests

Comment: I'm only using the `changedTouches` property of the event - so I only added that property to the event. If you are using `touches array` then add that instead